# Asp.Net Core Full Framework compile error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I created an `ASP.NET Core .Net` Web Application (.Net Framework) and reference Data library.
In Data library, I added `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` from the *Nuget Package Manager*.

When I build it, I got the error

> Failed to make the following project runnable:
>   SiteApp (.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2) reason:
>   The process cannot access the file '\packages\sqlite.3.13.0\runtimes\win7-x64\native\sqlite3.dll' because it is being used by another process.

If I remove the Data library and add all classes to the site APP and add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`, it works.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How i can seperate to Data library?